# OS X 10.8.2 python 3 import sqlite error

Tags: macos, sqlite, python-3.x

Both brew installed python3 and manually compiled python3 with -–enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions fails when import sqlite from python3 shell. Please help!

Comment: Sorry, ignore the above comment. Error message: Python 3.3.0 (default, Feb 11 2013, 08:22:56) 
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew provides python3 with sqlite3 support and loadable modules.

`brew install python3` will do the right thing (and brew sqlite, too).

There was a bug, that probably struck you, but it has been [fixed](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commit/71a4d6038b34ebe16f7908380e4c790e9f6b36cc)

Answer (score 2):

The module is named `sqlite3`, not `sqlite`:

```
import sqlite3
```

http://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Update: Now that we've cleared up the module name, the problem being reported:

```
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

means that your Python instance cannot find the C extension module, `_sqlite3.so`, that is part of the `sqlite3` module in the standard library.  Since the file path of the `dbapi2.py` in the traceback looks reasonable, the issue is probably not a path issue (`sys.path`).  Most likely the `_sqlite3` extension module failed to build or link.  Check the output from your Python build for errors.  OS X 10.8 includes a version of `sqlite3` but for security reasons it does not include the optional loadable extensions feature.  Your Python build likely included this message:

```
Failed to build these modules:
_sqlite3
```

and, earlier, this:

```
*** WARNING: renaming "_sqlite3" since importing it failed: dlopen(build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3-pydebug/_sqlite3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3-pydebug/_sqlite3.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-3.3-pydebug/_sqlite3.so
```

The solution is to build and install a separate copy of sqlite3 that is built with the loadable extensions feature.  If you are using Homebrew, its [`sqlite` recipe with the `with-functions` option](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/sqlite.rb) should do that.  Then rebuild Python.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ned. I think brew install sqlite --with-functions completed just fine, but brew install python3 still ended up with same import sqlite3 error. My guess is it did not know about the brew installed version of sqlite, and still linked to the system sqlite. Any idea how to link python3 to brew sqlite? In the end, [a hint from github](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17765) gave me what I wanted, but it doesn't feel like the right way to do it. I wonder if this will lead to conflict with the system sqlite3 later down the line.

Comment: I don't follow Homebrew development closely but, in general, the project is quite careful to avoid conflicts with Apple-supplied software.  It's not a problem to have more than one copy of the sqlite3 lib installed in different locations.