# Missing sqlite3 after Python3 compile

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, compilation

My question is much like several others. Having manually compiled Python, sqlite3 is missing:

[image]

The main difference is that I'm using a Debian Linux system (unlike in this question: [OS X 10.8.2 python 3 import sqlite error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817507/)), and Python3 (unlike in this and a bunch of other questions: [Cannot import SQLite with Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233320/)).

**I was hoping for some guidance on which direction to troubleshoot in.** According to some of the Linux-but-older-Python questions, an error like the one I'm getting could be caused by *a missing resource* during linking or something (_sqlite3.so). I have two such files on my system, both of them in older Python installations, ... but nothing related to Python3. Or is one of these good enough? Or they say to *install the libsqlite3-dev package*, then to re-compile Python. I did this, but I don't see how just having this package on my system will affect the compilation process. And indeed, it didn't. A second compile gave me a second Python without sqlite3.

I wish I could just do `apt-get install python3`, but Debian, in its stability, only has Python 3.2, where I need the latest version. Thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to install `libsqlite3` (Debian based) or `sqlite-devel` (RedHat based) and the associated header files before compiling Python because Python needs to find them during the compile process.

Did you make sure to run:

1. `./configure`
2. `make`
3. `make install`

In this specific order? With no missing steps?

Comment: How do I make Python find them during the compile process? I mentioned that I had tried installing that exact package.

Comment: @Bepetersn I was updating the answer, can you check you did follow those three steps? If it still doesn't work, can you show any warnings that show up during the compile process?

Comment: @Bepetersn the key step here is `./configure`. You should check its output for sqlite3.

Comment: When I complied python 2.7 by hand on RHEL6, the compiler would crash while trying to build the sqlite3 module due to a 64-bit error and a typedef. (Not sure where I found that link) Try compiling python again, and look very closely at the output and see why (I think) the sqlite module is crashing during compilation.

Comment: "checking for --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions... no": This is the only reference to sqlite from ./configure's output. I'm `make install`ing right now.

Comment: @Bepetersn For future reference, `configure` is the step that searches for available libraries. Header files (those contained in the `-dev` package) are files that tell the compiler how to build against the sqlite binaries that are on your system.

Comment: I'm on raspberry pi with Raspbian (debian-based distribution) and I already had the following package installed libsqlite3-0, but it did not help and python did not build _sqlite3 library. But after I installed: libsqlite3-dev, it did. I thought this would help somebody out there.

Comment: You need to install libsqlite3-dev on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 23):

After `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

then

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.7.4 --with-ssl --with-pydebug

make
make install
```

Note: You might need `apt-get install libssl-dev` aslo, openssl version must above **1.0.2** if you are compiling python3.7

For me, I'm using ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) I can't find a `libssl-dev` package to meet the requirement compiling python3.7 with ssl support. I modify my  `/etc/apt/sourcelist.d`

```
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

after install a newer libssl-dev, then change it back to the original one

```
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
```

Comment: 1. --with-ssl seems not required now 2. libffi-dev is aslo required, otherwise there will be an error "No module named '_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing" when `make install`

Answer (score 3):

If you only have limited user access (no root or sudo permission) you can install to a local, user accessible, environment like so:

```
tar -xvf sqlite-autoconf-3270200.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3270200
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local
make && make install
```

This will install on your `~/.local` tree.

Add `~/.local/bin` to your path if missing.