# Path configuration for sqlite3 in python3.6

Tags: python, django, centos7, vps

I have a system Centos7 which has `python2.7` as default and `python3.6`. Then I am running the following command on my `django` `version=2.1` project `python3 manage.py migrate` but unfortunately I am having the following error `No _sqlite3 module`.

I did some research and found that I should install `sqlite-devel` but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your Python 3.6 was built with sqlite enabled. In that case there should be an `_sqlite3.so` in python3.6's `lib-dynload` directory.

If you are going to manually rebuild python 3, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750886/missing-sqlite3-after-python3-compile).