# Python, postgresql, psycopg2 getting a Sqlite3 error. Not using sqlite3

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, amazon-ec2

AWS EC2 linux2 Python3.10 code trying to insert into a Postgresql database.  Getting a Sqlite3 error message.

**Generates the message below**

Even though I'm not using Sqlite.
I am running in a virtual environment. It is activated.

Python 3.10 on an EC2 linux2 instance.

The version of postgresql is 14.7.

My requirements.txt is:

pandas>=1.3.0 
numpy>=1.21.6 
psycopg2-binary>=2.9.6 
pyarrow>=12.0.0 
openpyxl>=3.1.2 
fastparquet>=0.8.1 
watchdog>=2.1. 
parquet-tools 
pyspark 
sqlalchemy

pip list 
(.venv) @ec2-user:~/fluence-test-bench/.venv/include$ pip list
Package           Version 
----------------- -------- 
boto3             1.26.146 
botocore          1.29.146 
colorama          0.4.6 
cramjam           2.6.2 
cursor            1.3.5 
et-xmlfile        1.1.0 
fastparquet       2023.4.0 
fsspec            2023.5.0 
greenlet          2.0.2 
halo              0.0.29 
jmespath          1.0.1 
log-symbols       0.0.14 
numpy             1.24.3 
openpyxl          3.1.2 
packaging         23.1 
pandas            2.0.2 
parquet-tools     0.2.14 
pip               23.1.2 
psycopg2-binary   2.9.6 
py4j              0.10.9.7 
pyarrow           12.0.0 
pyspark           3.4.0 
python-dateutil   2.8.2 
pytz              2023.3 
s3transfer        0.6.1 
setuptools        65.5.0 
six               1.16.0 
spinners          0.0.24 
tabulate          0.8.10 
termcolor         2.3.0 
thrift            0.13.0 
typing_extensions 4.6.3 
tzdata            2023.3 
urllib3           1.26.16 
watchdog          3.0.0

````
    import  pandas as pd
    import  psycopg2 as sql
    from    sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from    sqlalchemy.sql import text
    
    conn_string = 'postgresql://...amazonaws.com/...'

    db = create_engine(conn_string)
    conn2 = db.connect()
    
    df = pd.read_parquet("files_by_count/Panda_1.parquet")
     
    conn2.execute(text('select *  from sensor_data_in;'))

   df.to_sql('sensor_data_in',con=conn2,if_exists='append',index=False)
    conn2.close()```


>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/fluence-test-bench/parq.py", line 24, in <module>
    df.to_sql('sensor_data_in',con=conn,if_exists='append',index=False)
  File "/home/ec2-user/fluence-test-bench/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2878, in to_sql
    return sql.to_sql(
  File "/home/ec2-user/fluence-test-bench/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 768, in to_sql
    with pandasSQL_builder(con, schema=schema, need_transaction=True) as pandas_sql:
  File "/home/ec2-user/fluence-test-bench/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 821, in pandasSQL_builder
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
````

Comment: You are mixing Pandas and psycopg2 when Pandas is looking for SQLAlchemy connection. Per [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) *con sqlalchemy.engine.(Engine or Connection) or sqlite3.Connection* Your `psycopg2` is not being seen as correct so Pandas is falling back to  a `sqlite3` connection attempt.

Comment: Installed sqlalchemy.  Added the create_engine connection, and still got the same error.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what is going on, especially as sqlite3 ships as a Python global module. How as Python installed on that machine?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, I agree about suspecting the Python install because this works perfectly on a Windows 10 box I have.  This is an EC2 machine and a coworker installed Python3 on it as it came with Python 2.7 something.  I am going to wait for him to get back and I will discuss with him.  I even installed pysqlite3 to no avail.  I will update this with the solution.  Thanks1

Comment: @BecWilson: I seem to have a similar problem, but only on a Linux machine (Centos 8), not on Windows 11. On both, Python 3.10.5 is running in a virtual environment. Could you find something in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the sqlite dev tools prior to compiling Python from source on your machine.
Check this: [Missing sqlite3 after Python3 compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750886/missing-sqlite3-after-python3-compile)

Answer (score 0):

From this line in the traceback

> File "/home/ec2-user/fluence-test-bench/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 821, in pandasSQL_builder
> import sqlite3

we can see that Pandas is trying to import Python's `sqlite3` module. This import is unconditional; Pandas will always try to import `sqlite3` because it will try to create an SQLite connection as a fallback if no connection is provided to `to_sql` and similar methods.

It would seem that the Python build on your instance does not include `sqlite3`.

Depending on the OS/Python install on your instance, you will need to either use the OS package manager to install Python's `sqlite3` module or install SQLite and its headers and then recompile Python.